# Google Oauth2.0 endpoint returns 404 Error

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to get the access token using an http request.
According to the Oauth guide:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth
the endpoint for exchanging authorization code to access token is `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` but it gives a page can't be found HTTP 404 error
Here's my entire url (I've replaced the code, client id, and secrets)

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?
code=xxxxx&
client_id=xxxxx&
client_secret=xxxxx&
redirect_uri=http://localhost&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Comment: I would suggest using https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground  initially to build your OAuth mechanism and see if it is working fine. If this too is failing with 404 then it would indicate a server error otherwise you may copy the entire URL that is built there and test further.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in the required fields as query parameters, but you need to put them in the post body and send an HTTPS POST request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token. You can find this information further down in the documentation you were referring to: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_7.

Comment: Is there a way to send the post request as an url?